# VueJS: Multiple arrays, remove values in other arrays when chosen in any one array

Tags: vue.js

Trying to get a master array and 3 separate v-models of checkboxes. Once the value in the first array has been selected, remove it from the other 2 arrays or just disable it so you cannot choose the same value for multiple arrays. Same would go if they chose something in array #3, it would be disabled in #1 and #2.

```
<div>
    <h6>DSCP Values in Q1</h6>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="(option, index) in dscpValues.dscpData" :key="index">
            <li>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    :id="option.id"
                    :value="option.value"
                    v-model="dscpChoiceQ1"
                />
                <label for="id">{{ option.value }}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h6>DSCP Values in Q2</h6>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="(option, index) in dscpValues.dscpData" :key="index">
            <li>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    :id="option.id"
                    :value="option.value"
                    v-model="dscpChoiceQ2"
                />
                <label for="id">{{ option.value }}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h6>DSCP Values in Q3</h6>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="(option, index) in dscpValues.dscpData" :key="index">
            <li>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    :id="option.id"
                    :value="option.value"
                    v-model="dscpChoiceQ3"
                />
                <label for="id">{{ option.value }}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I display them down the page with 3 separate v-models, add them via the setup function and call the same array from the Vue store. Is there a better way to do this?

```
const dscpChoiceQ1 = ref([]);
const dscpChoiceQ2 = ref([]);
const dscpChoiceQ3 = ref([]);
const dscpValuesQ1 = computed({
    get: () => {
        const v = dscpChoiceQ1.value;
        return v.join(' ');
    },
    set: (newval) => {
        dscpChoiceQ1.value = newval;
    }
});
const dscpValuesQ2 = computed({
    get: () => {
        const v = dscpChoiceQ2.value;
        return v.join(' ');
    },
    set: (newval) => {
        dscpChoiceQ2.value = newval;
    }
});
const dscpValuesQ3 = computed({
    get: () => {
        const v = dscpChoiceQ3.value;
        return v.join(' ');
    },
    set: (newval) => {
        dscpChoiceQ3.value = newval;
    }
});
```

My store Array:

```
state: {
    dscpData: [
        { id: 'cs0', value: 'CS0' },
        { id: 'cs1', value: 'CS1' },
        { id: 'cs2', value: 'CS2' },
        { id: 'cs3', value: 'CS3' },
        { id: 'cs4', value: 'CS4' },
        { id: 'cs5', value: 'CS5' },
        { id: 'cs6', value: 'CS6' },
        { id: 'cs7', value: 'CS7' },
        { id: 'af11', value: 'AF11' },
        { id: 'af12', value: 'AF12' },
        { id: 'af13', value: 'AF13' },
        { id: 'af21', value: 'AF21' },
        { id: 'af22', value: 'AF22' },
        { id: 'af23', value: 'AF23' },
        { id: 'af31', value: 'AF31' },
        { id: 'af32', value: 'AF32' },
        { id: 'af33', value: 'AF33' },
        { id: 'af41', value: 'AF41' },
        { id: 'af42', value: 'AF42' },
        { id: 'af43', value: 'AF43' },
        { id: 'ef', value: 'EF' }
    ]
}
```

I appreciate any and all help with this, been pulling my hair out for days!

Answer (score 1):

for v-for and your key, would be way better to use option.id. Currently you will push Bool to your arrays not id of the checkbox. and for checking if your field is already checked you need some kind of a flag, you can add another prop in your dscpData item or create another array with checked ids and compare with original to see whats selected.

Another thing is that you creating 3 lists from same array. Their id will be same, so your input id and label for attribute will go crazy

please check this working example, not ideal but will give an idea :) :
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-water-9g94n?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue